# (node:8604) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...`

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been trying to make a discord bot and every time, my bot sends something in the chat, I get this error written in the title in the console.

My code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if (command === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('pong!')
    } else if (command === 'turn-off') {
        if (message.author.id === '000000000000000000') {
            message.channel.send('Shutting down...')
            let interval0 = setInterval(turnOff, 1000)

            function turnOff() {
                clearInterval(interval0)
                console.log('Shutting down...')
                client.destroy()
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(
                "You don't have required permissions to use this command!"
            )
        }
    }
})
```

I tried replacing "message" to "messageCreate" on the part where it was sending something in chat, or even replacing every "message" with "messageCreate".

Does anybody know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to the [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) event instead of the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  /* ... */
})
```